# Does Angular have named routes or states like UIRouter?

Tags: angular, url, angular-ui-router

In AngularJS we do (with ui-router) when define a state:

```
.state('myState', { 
  url: 'some-user-friendly-url'
  ...
})
```

So we have a way to set `url` and `name`. It's nice to have so we don't worry about url and remember only state name when we want to use `$state.go('myState')`.

I'm getting started with Angular, but in its native router there is `path` that is used with `routerLink` directive to go to a route and in the same time use it as the url.

Does the native router have a solution for that case? Or it's again better to go with UI-router for Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular(2+) Router doesn't have named states - the same thing you would do with UI-Router of saying `$state.go(<some state name>)`, you would do with the Angular Router by using `router.navigate(<some path>)`. My personal recommendation would be to try the Angular Router to see if you actually miss those named states. UI Router served a real need with AngularJS since the default router was so limited. The new Router learned a lot from UI Router (and other Routers) and is much more capable, so I would suggest trying it out to see if it serves your needs.

But, you can also use UI Router as well in Angular, if you must have your states.

Comment: Thanks for response, I don't know if it's only my habit, but I think it's super nice when you can split navigation and the way you think about states and urls that appear in the browser address bar.
Secondly it's nice in terms of code base support, when I have state and use it in html, components to navigate by name, I don't think how url is looks like, I can change url without any pain, in case I use url for navigation logic I have to update each usage...

Comment: Don't get me wrong - i do understand the benefits of divorcing state from url, but although that was a great feature of UI Router, i think UI Router took over AngularJS more because of shortcomings of the builtin ngRoute than because of that feature specifically. I know that early implementations of the new Router had named routes, but they ripped it out during one of the rewrites - i guess for most use cases, the names were redundant with the urls.

Comment: The Angular Router is really good at composing routes with individual parts and/or have routing relative to the current component, so your urls can adapt easily to changes in your component structure. It's not like you have to always construct full urls in your `router.navigate()` method, so there's a lot more flexibility than you might first think

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me good inside regarding `relative` routing!
I think that would be enough for me.